# Fail to save user to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, multer

**If I remain this code, the program still working, my image will upload backend to frontend normally**

```
router.post('/admin/register', upload.single('avatar'), async (req, res) => {
// Handle add image by multer
... handel file upload from front-end


return res.json({ avatar: newFullPath });
  }
);
```

**I started save user to mongoDB and error occur**

```
router.post('/admin/register', upload.single('avatar'), async (req, res) => {
    // Handle add image by multer
    ... handel file upload from front-end

   //Handle add user to database
       const user = {
          ...JSON.parse(req.body.user),
          avatar: newFullPath
       }; // { first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Wick', avatar: .... }

       const { error } = Validation.adminRegisterValidation(user);
       if (error) {
        return res.json({ error: error.details[0].message });
       }  // working as I expected

       const emailExist = await User.findOne({ email: user.email });
       if (emailExist) {
          return res.json({ error: 'Email already exist!' });
       } // working as I expected

       // If I commented this block of code, program still run as I expected, but if I don't do 
       // that, the program crashed ( Error: Below images ) 
       const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 10);
       const addUser = new User({
         first_name: user.first_name,
         last_name: user.last_name,
         avatar: user.avatar
       });
       await addUser.save();

    return res.json({ avatar: newFullPath });
      }
);
```

> This project in my Github repository: [This project in Github](https://github.com/hanh040499/shoe-shop)

[Error shows in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA3pR.png)

[Error in Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqQ4m.png)

Comment: why does this error occur?

Comment: Yo seem to be having a cors error, for me, the cors() module didnt work